# extract ranges from column values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I've column of values 1-10 missing 4 and 7 can I extract 1-3,5-6,7-10.
Currently I'm using this formula **=IF(A3=A2+1,C2,C2+1)** which gives me helper column sort of help
but my list is long If I could extract ranges that would be helpful.
There are no duplicates

Comment: Can you edit your question and show your data?

Comment: Column C is empty so your result will be zero…

Comment: What eactly do you mean by `If I could extract ranges that would be helpful.`?  Please show the desired output.

Comment: Desired output would be 16028130-16028134, 16028136-1628137, 16028139, 16028142, 16028144-16028147 etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand exactly what you mean, but this is what I have done until now: I have copied the same columns A and B, and I have added following columns:

- Column C : `=COUNTIF(B$2:B$16,B2)`
- Column D : `=IF(AND(C2=C3,C3<>C4),"End",IF(AND(C2<>C3,C3=C4),"Begin"))`

The result looks as follows:

[image]

As you can see:

- The number 1 from column B ends at row 6, and D6 indeed indicates "End".
- The number 2 from B starts at row 7 (D7="Begin") and ends at row 8 (D8="End").
- The numbers 3 and 4 are not correctly handled but:
- As far as 5 is concerned: it starts at row 11 (D11="Begin") and ends at row 15 (D15="End").

There still is some finetuning to do but I guess you see how the ranges start being unfold.